# in `_main': undefined method `run' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't call the run method in a class called MySqliteRequest. When I call the method,the error is going out.

```
in `main': undefined method `run' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Here some methods of `MySqliteRequest`

```
class MySqliteRequest
    def print
        puts "Type Of Request #{@type_of_request}"
    end

    def run
        print
    end

    def _setTypeOfRequest(new_type)
        if(@type_of_request == :none or @type_of_request == new_type)
            @type_of_request = new_type
        else
            raise "Invalid: type of request already set #{@type_of_request} (new type => #{new_type}"
        end
    end
end
```

And main method ↓

```
def _main()
   request = MySqliteRequest.new
   request = request.from('nba_player_data.csv')
   request = request.select('name')
   request = request.where('birth_state', 'Indiana')
   request.run
end
_main()
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Instead, please edit your question (by clicking in the *Edit* link below it) and add all relevant code to the question directly. Please also include the full error message as well as a textual description of what you would expect to happen and what happened instead. If you make it easy for people to answer your question by providing enough information, you will actually get answers. But **you** have to provide enough details to make this possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point where you call `request.run` the value for `request` is `nil`. This is why you are seeing the error you're given.
This is happening because the line right above it assigns the `nil` value to the `request` variable.

You are clearly coming from another language that is not Ruby (some type of C maybe?), by how you've formatted things. It would help for you to get more familiar with Ruby and its idioms. However, best I can tell, you want to do something like this instead:

```
def _main
   request = MySqliteRequest.new
   request.from('nba_player_data.csv')
   request.select('name')
   request.where('birth_state', 'Indiana')
   request.run
end
_main()
```

This assumes you've also defined (and in some cases probably overridden) these methods on your `MySqliteRequest` Object or Model:
`from`
`select`
`where`

However, please note that the way you're going about this is just completely against how Ruby and Ruby on Rails is designed to work.